# SWT app on Mac: Minimum requirements if I support Cocoa, but not Carbon?

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, swt, macos-carbon

I want to deploy an SWT application on Mac OS X. Since I'm relatively new to the Mac world, I'm a bit confused about the whole Carbon vs. Cocoa thing. Currently, SWT provides different jars for Carbon and Cocoa. So, if I decide to ship only with the Cocoa jar, what would be the minimum requirements for my application? Would it run, for example, on Mac OS X 10.5 and later? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Mac OS X 10.3 Panther Cocoa is available.

Comment: Do you mean the Cocoa jar for SWT? Cocoa itself has been part of Mac OS X since before it was called Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: See the [SWT FAQ](http://eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#osxvms). Specifically, these are the minimum requirements for Cocoa SWT:

> Mac OS X (Mac/Cocoa) - This 32-bit port needs a Java 5 VM and runs on
>   Leopard (OS X v10.5). Mac OS X (Mac/Cocoa/x86_64) - This 64-bit port
>   needs a Java 5 or Java 6 VM and runs on Leopard.

Longer answer: Stick with the 64-bit Cocoa version. Carbon hasn't been updated in 2 years, and is no longer being built. Java 7 on OS X is 64-bit only.